# How do I calculate the entropy of a uniform continuous variable?

Tags: entropy

> Let $x$ be any random rational number where $x \in (0, 1/8)$ and $f(x) = 8x$.
> Therefore, $f(x) \in (0, 1)$. How would I mathematically calculate the
> entropy of $x$ and $f(x)$?

Applying the differential entropy formula, I get $\log_2(1/8) = -3$ bits of entropy for $x$ and $\log_2(1) = 0$ bits entropy for $f(x)$. I assume this is incorrect as $f(x)$ provides complete information about what $x$ is. So how would I accurately calculate the entropy for $x$ and $f(x)$?

Note: This is a dummy example. I want to extend the general idea to more complex functions.

Comment: Your calculation is correct. Differential entropy is not invariant under change of variables, and can't be interpreted as "amount of information" as in the discrete case

Comment: @J.Delaney Is there a way to calculate the "amount of information" for a continuous variable?

Comment: Not really. If you think of a Gaussian for example, there is no meaning in asking how "broad" or "narrow" it is, because you can always scale the x-axis. You can only ask it relative to some other length scale or distribution, hence the notion of  [relative entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)

Comment: @J.Delaney So if I understand correctly, I need to find the amount of information $x$ stores relative to the amount of information $f(x)$ stores. What would be a good way to find this?